# Why spark task id not executed in order?

Tags: apache-spark

I run the simplest program wordcount, code below:

```scala
val text = spark.read.textFile("/datasets/wordcount_512m.txt")
text.flatMap(line => line.split(" ")).groupByKey(identity).count().collect()
```

And my HDFS block size is 128MB, tow executors and each executor has two cores. And I looked into the SPARK UI, in stage 0, it's normal.

[image]

There are four tasks run in parallel.

But a strange thing happened in stage 1, some task id do not execute in order.
[image]
[image]

As the picture show, some bigger task id run before small task id(task 91 run before task 0 ). What are these abnormal task ids represent for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SPARK Stages within a Job must execute in order, else none of it would make sense computationally.

Within a Stage there are Tasks - 1 per partition. It does not matter in which order these tasks execute, as long as they complete. That is the parallel compute notion - no dependencies. The scheduling of these is not relevant.

Comment: But why are the subsequent task ids arranged in order? Only the first 4 task ids are abnormal.

Comment: if you got the right answer, then there is nothing abnormal, see answer.